# RxJS - Iterate over returned data from ajax

Tags: ajax, rxjs

I am using RxJS Ajax() to return a bunch of GitHub users.  I want to iterate over each one and just get the `login` names from each user.  I am able to iterate over a local array of objects, but not if that array of objects came from Ajax, whether or not I force it to be a stream with RxJS `from()`.

```
// from() the array of objects (locally defined)
let localArrayOfObj = from([
  { login: 'Barbara Holland', loggedIn: false, token: null },
  { login: 'Joyce Byers', loggedIn: true, token: 'abc' },
  { login: 'Nancy Wheeler', loggedIn: true, token: '123' }
]);
// Return the "login" names:
localArrayOfObj.pipe(
  map((data) => data.login)
).subscribe(console.log);   // This returns the login names

// from() the array of objects (returned by Ajax)
const githubUsers = `https://api.github.com/users?per_page=2`;
const arrayFromAjax = from(ajax.getJSON(githubUsers));
arrayFromAjax.subscribe(console.log);
// Trying the same to return the "login" names:
arrayFromAjax.pipe(
  map((data) => data.login)
).subscribe(console.log);   // This is undefined
```

I'm putting the results of the Ajax call through RxJS `from()` so both arrays are treated the same, however the same `undefined` results occur if I skip `from()` and just do

```
const arrayFromAjax = ajax.getJSON(githubUsers);
```

instead of

```
const arrayFromAjax = from(ajax.getJSON(githubUsers));
```

How is an array of objects from Ajax() different than a similar locally defined array of objects? And how can I iterate over the Ajax results?

Answer (score 1):

The `from()` operator creates an observable that emits the provided values **one at at time**, so you are not receiving an array, you are receiving individual objects.

`ajax.getJSON(githubUsers)` returns an array of objects.  This is why you are seeing differences between these two cases.

You can alter your test case with local array to the following the match the same shape:

```
let localArrayOfObj = from([
  [
    { login: 'Barbara Holland', loggedIn: false, token: null },
    { login: 'Joyce Byers', loggedIn: true, token: 'abc' },
    { login: 'Nancy Wheeler', loggedIn: true, token: '123' }
  ]
]);
```

In your code here: `data` is an array, so if you want to modify the elements individually you can do something like:

```
arrayFromAjax.pipe(
  map((dataArray) => dataArray.map(data => data.login))
).subscribe(console.log);   // This is undefined
```

Comment: even better just use `of()`

Comment: ha ha, yeah that's better :-)

Comment: Update - the solution for using Ajax this way is RxJS `switchMap()`.  The explanation I found states "SwitchMap takes the values from the outer observable (returned by the of operator) and pass those as a parameter to a function which has to return a new observable."